# Why does error handling after calling a batch file not work as expected in my batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I am trying call `Run_sqlldr_process.bat` from within batch file `run_process.bat`.

This is how the call is invoked in `run_process.bat`:

```
call %FWK_DIR%\run_sqlldr_process.bat !ldr!.ctl !log!.log !bad!.bad !data!.dat %BATCHUSER% %BATCHPWD% %ORACLE_SID%
echo %ERRORLEVEL%
echo %RC%
```

There is a failure inside `run_sqlldr_process.bat` after which `run_sqlldr_process.bat` exits with return code `1` as assigned to environment variable `RC`. But `run_process.bat` does not capture the error return code from `run_sqlldr_process.bat`. Both `echo` statements output `0` and `run_process.bat` completes successfully.

File `Run_sqlldr_process.bat`:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

REM ##########################################################################
REM # Program Name: run_process.bat
REM # Description:
REM #   This script is a part of the batch framework. It contains the common
REM #   functions for running batch jobs.
REM #
REM # Usage:
REM #   run_process.bat <processname>
REM #
REM # History:
REM # Date        Who                 Description
REM # ----------  ------------------  ----------------------------------------
REM # 01-Jun-2014  Ilavarasan Sekar      Created
REM ##########################################################################

SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT=RRRR-MM-DD-HH24:MI

FOR /F "TOKENS=1* DELIMS= " %%A IN ('DATE/T') DO SET CDATE=%%B
FOR /F "TOKENS=1,2 eol=/ DELIMS=/ " %%A IN ('DATE/T') DO SET mm=%%B
FOR /F "TOKENS=1,2 DELIMS=/ eol=/" %%A IN ('echo %CDATE%') DO SET dd=%%B
FOR /F "TOKENS=2,3 DELIMS=/ " %%A IN ('echo %CDATE%') DO SET yyyy=%%B
SET todaysdate=%yyyy%%mm%%dd%
SET WORKFLOWLOGMONTH=%mm%%yyyy%
SET DATETIMESTAMP=%todaysdate%
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=:." %%a in ("%time%") do SET timestamp=%%a%%b%%c
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims= " %%a in ("%timestamp%") do SET trimmed_timestamp=%%a%%b%%c
SET TIMESTAMP=%DATETIMESTAMP%_%trimmed_timestamp%


rem --- Initialize --------------------------------------------
rem Install error handler.
rem basename=$(basename $0)
SET dirname=D:/JDA/Batch_FWK/fwk
echo off
SET oldpwd=%~dp0
SET suffix=%date%

SET process_id=%1
SET job_id=
SET process_type=
SET preprocess_type=
SET postprocess_type=
SET job_status=CREATED
SET job_status_message=
SET log_level=INFO
SET pre=

if "%1" == "" goto show_usage

rem --- Include environment variables -------------------------
SET batchenv=%dirname%\batchenv.bat
if exist %batchenv% (

    call %batchenv%

 ) else (
  echo "Environment file missing.\n"
  goto end
)

set LOG_FILE=%LOG_DIR%\%process_id%_%TIMESTAMP%.log
set TMP_FILE=%TMP_DIR%\%process_id%_%TIMESTAMP%.tmp


rem --- Start job ---------------------------------------------

call:start_job

IF "%preprocess_type%"=="SQL" (

  call:log_info "SQL."
  SET pre=%SQL_DIR%\%process_id%_pre
  call %FWK_DIR%\run_sql_process.bat !pre!.sql

) ELSE IF "%preprocess_type%"=="CMD" (

   call:log_info "CMD."
   SET pre=%CMD_DIR%\%process_id%_pre
   call %FWK_DIR%\run_cmd_process.bat !pre!.bat 

) ELSE (
  call:log_info "No postprocess_type."

)

IF %ERRORLEVEL% GTR 0 (
    set job_status=FAILED
    call:end_job
    call:cleanup
    set RC=1
    goto end 

 )


rem --- Execute main process ----------------------------------

IF "%process_type%"=="SQL" (

   call:log_info "SQL."

   SET main=%SQL_DIR%\%process_id%
   call %FWK_DIR%\run_sql_process.bat !main!.sql

) ELSE IF "%process_type%"=="CMD" (

  call:log_info "CMD."
  SET main=%CMD_DIR%\%process_id%
  call %FWK_DIR%\run_cmd_process.bat !main!.bat

) ELSE IF "%process_type%"=="SRE" (

  call:log_info "SRE."
  SET main=%XML_DIR%\%process_id%
  call %FWK_DIR%\run_sre_process.bat !main!.xml

) ELSE IF "%process_type%"=="PERL" (

  call:log_info "PERL."
  SET main=%PRL_DIR%\%process_id%
  call %FWK_DIR%\run_perl_process.bat !main!.pl

) ELSE IF "%process_type%"=="SQLLDR" (

  call:log_info "SQLLDR."
  SET ldr=%CTL_DIR%\%process_id%
  SET log=%LOG_DIR%\%process_id%_%TIMESTAMP%
  SET bad=%BAD_DIR%\%process_id%_%TIMESTAMP%
  SET data=%IN_DIR%\%process_id%
  call %FWK_DIR%\run_sqlldr_process.bat !ldr!.ctl !log!.log !bad!.bad !data!.dat %BATCHUSER% %BATCHPWD% %ORACLE_SID%
  echo Return Code ERRORLEVEL inside run_process is %ERRORLEVEL%
  echo Return Code inside run_process.bat  is %RC%


IF %RC% GTR 0 (
    ECHO INSIDE FAILED BLOCK
    set job_status=FAILED
    set RC=1
    call:end_job
    call:cleanup
    goto end 
 )

) ELSE (
  call:log_info "Unsupported process type %process_type%."
    set job_status=FAILED
    set RC=1
    call:end_job
    call:cleanup
    goto end
)

IF %ERRORLEVEL% GTR 0 (
    set job_status=FAILED
    set RC=1
    call:end_job
    call:cleanup
    goto end 
 )


IF "%postprocess_type%"=="SQL" (

    call:log_info "SQL."
    SET post=%SQL_DIR%\%process_id%_post
    call %FWK_DIR%\run_sql_process.bat !post!.sql
) ELSE IF "%postprocess_type%"=="CMD" (

  call:log_info "CMD."
   SET post=%CMD_DIR%\%process_id%_post
   call %FWK_DIR%\run_cmd_process.bat !post!.bat    

) ELSE (

  call:log_info "No postprocess_type."
)

IF %ERRORLEVEL% GTR 0 (
    set job_status=FAILED
    set RC=1
    call:end_job
    call:cleanup
    goto end 
 )


rem --- End job -------------------------------------------------

call:end_job
call:cleanup
goto end 


:show_usage

@echo Usage: Usage is run_process.bat ProcessName

goto end

rem --- Function definitions ----------------------------------
rem -----------------------------------------------------------
rem Function Name: start_job
rem Description  :
rem   Retrieve process properties and start a new job for
rem   the specified process.
rem Input        : process_id - Process to start.
rem Output       : job_id - New job id set.
rem -----------------------------------------------------------

:start_job
  call:log_info "--- Starting -----------------------------------"
  call:log_info "Process          : %process_id%"
  call:log_info "Environment      : %ENV_NAME%"
  call:log_info "Batch root       : %ENV_HOME%"
  call:log_info "Log file         : %LOG_FILE%"
  call:log_info "Tmp file         : %TMP_FILE%"

  sqlplus -s /nolog @%dirname%/sqlFile.sql '%BATCHUSER%' '%BATCHPWD%' '%ORACLE_SID%' '%process_id%'

  for /f "tokens=2 delims=|" %%a in ('findstr /R /I "^JOB_ID" %tmp_file%') do set JOB_ID=%%a
  for /f "tokens=1,*" %%a in ("%JOB_ID%") do set JOB_ID=%%a
  for /f "tokens=2 delims=|" %%a in ('findstr /R /I "^PROCESS_TYPE" %tmp_file%') do set PROCESS_TYPE=%%a
  for /f "tokens=1,*" %%a in ("%PROCESS_TYPE%") do set PROCESS_TYPE=%%a
  for /f "tokens=2 delims=|" %%a in ('findstr /R /I "^PREPROCESS_TYPE" %tmp_file%') do set PREPROCESS_TYPE=%%a
  for /f "tokens=1,*" %%a in ("%PREPROCESS_TYPE%") do set PREPROCESS_TYPE=%%a
  for /f "tokens=2 delims=|" %%a in ('findstr /R /I "^POSTPROCESS_TYPE" %tmp_file%') do set POSTPROCESS_TYPE=%%a
  for /f "tokens=1,*" %%a in ("%POSTPROCESS_TYPE%") do set POSTPROCESS_TYPE=%%a
  for /f "tokens=2 delims=|" %%a in ('findstr /R /I "^LOG_LEVEL" %tmp_file%') do set LOG_LEVEL=%%a
  for /f "tokens=1,*" %%a in ("%LOG_LEVEL%") do set LOG_LEVEL=%%a

  set job_status=RUNNING
  del /q %TMP_FILE% 

  IF "%job_id%" == ""  (
    set job_status=FAILED
    call:cleanup
    set RC=1
    goto end 
 )

  call:log_info "Job id           : %job_id%"
  call:log_info "Process type     : %process_type%"
  call:log_info "Pre-process type : %preprocess_type%"
  call:log_info "Post-process type: %postprocess_type%"
  call:log_info "--- Running ------------------------------------"  
 goto:eof

rem -----------------------------------------------------------
rem Function Name: end_job
rem Description  :
rem   End the current job.
rem Input        : job_id
rem Output       : N/A
rem -----------------------------------------------------------
:end_job

  call:log_info "--- Ending -------------------------------------"


 sqlplus -s /nolog @%dirname%/sqlFileEnd.sql '%BATCHUSER%' '%BATCHPWD%' '%ORACLE_SID%' '%job_id%' '%job_status%'

  for /f "tokens=2 delims=|" %%a in ('findstr /R /I "^JOB_STATUS|" %tmp_file%') do set JOB_STATUS=%%a
  for /f "tokens=1,*" %%a in ("%JOB_STATUS%") do set JOB_STATUS=%%a
  for /f "tokens=2 delims=|" %%a in ('findstr /R /I "^JOB_STATUS_MESSAGE" %tmp_file%') do set JOB_STATUS_MESSAGE=%%a
  for /f "tokens=1,*" %%a in ("%JOB_STATUS_MESSAGE%") do set JOB_STATUS_MESSAGE=%%a
  for /f "tokens=2 delims=|" %%a in ('findstr /R /I "^JOB_VOLUME" %tmp_file%') do set JOB_VOLUME=%%a
  for /f "tokens=1,*" %%a in ("%JOB_VOLUME%") do set JOB_VOLUME=%%a
  for /f "tokens=2 delims=|" %%a in ('findstr /R /I "^JOB_ERROR_COUNT" %tmp_file%') do set JOB_ERROR_COUNT=%%a
  for /f "tokens=1,*" %%a in ("%JOB_ERROR_COUNT%") do set JOB_ERROR_COUNT=%%a
  for /f "tokens=2 delims=|" %%a in ('findstr /R /I "^JOB_WARNING_COUNT" %tmp_file%') do set JOB_WARNING_COUNT=%%a
  for /f "tokens=1,*" %%a in ("%JOB_WARNING_COUNT%") do set JOB_WARNING_COUNT=%%a

   del /q %TMP_FILE% 
  call:log_info "Job status       : %job_status%"
  call:log_info "Job status msg   : %job_status_message%"
  rem call:log_info "Volume           : %job_volume%"
  call:log_info "Error count      : %job_error_count%"
  call:log_info "Warning count    : %job_warning_count%"    


goto:eof

rem -----------------------------------------------------------
rem Function Name: fatal
rem Description  :
rem   Error handler called called by trap on error etc.
rem   Handle clean up and exit with error.
rem Input        : Return code from failed command in ?.
rem Output       : N/A
rem -----------------------------------------------------------



rem -----------------------------------------------------------
rem Function Name: clear
rem Description  :
rem   Handle clean up.
rem Input        : N/A
rem Output       : N/A
rem -----------------------------------------------------------
:cleanup 

 if not '%job_status%' == 'COMPLETED' (
 call:log_info "--------- Ended with failure -------------------------"
 ) else (
 call:log_info "----------------------- End --------------------------"
 )
goto:eof


rem -----------------------------------------------------------
rem Function Name: log_info
rem Description  :
rem   Write information to log file and stdout.
rem Input        : 1 - Message to log.
rem Output       : N/A
rem -----------------------------------------------------------
:log_info

  set stamp=%TIMESTAMP%
  rem echo [INFO.][%stamp%] %1
  rem echo.
  rem echo %LOG_FILE%
  echo [INFO.][%stamp%] %1 >> %LOG_FILE%
  echo. >> %LOG_FILE%

goto:eof

:end
exit /b %RC%
endlocal
```

Why does error handling after calling a batch file not work as expected in my batch file?

Comment: Without seeing what `run_sqlldr_process.bat` does it's quite hard to tell you what's wrong. Anyway, I'd begin to put quotes around all the file paths/names...

Comment: added the code of run_process.bat in answer below.

Comment: I think I found your issue, you didn't SET the value of the "FWK_DIR" Variable.  `If you don;t populate your variables you're gonna have a bad time.`    Your code is quite verbose, I have had to clean it up a built in order to realise what was happening here.  I will post an answer with that code and let you see if that will solve your issue

Answer (score 1):

I have re-written your CMD script to be MUCh tighter, and I Put in a variable to set the FWK variable, and there are other variables that are being set that are not being used I removed many of them from here, and there are additional script variables that are not being set by you from anywhere That I ca find, perhaps they are coming from the other .bat file?>

Lets go through this in chat in more detail as there are several unknowns and I obviously can;t test this myself as it depends so heavily on the custom scripts you have.

```
:: ##########################################################################
:: # Program Name: run_process.bat
:: # Description:
:: #   This script is a part of the batch framework. It contains the common
:: #   functions for running batch jobs.
:: #
:: # Usage:
:: #   run_process.bat <processname>
:: #
:: # History:
:: # Date        Who                 Description
:: # ----------  ------------------  ----------------------------------------
:: # 01-Jun-2014  Ilavarasan Sekar      Created
:: ##########################################################################
::


@(
  echo off
  SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
  SET "_eLvl=0"
  IF /I "%1" EQU "" (
    CALL :Show_Usage
    Exit /B 1
  )
  REM ENTER YOUR DIRECTORIES
  SET "dirname=D:\JDA\Batch_FWK\fwk"
  SET "FWK_DIR=C:\SOME\DIRECTORY"

  REM If Batch Environment Bat File is missing Quit!  Otherwise load it and continue
  SET "batchenv=!dirname!\batchenv.bat"
  IF NOT EXIST "!batchenv!" (
    ECHO Environment file !batchenv!" is missing.
    Exit /B 1
  )
  CALL "!batchenv!"
  SET "_Write-Info=call :log_info "
)

CALL :Main

(
  ENDLOCAL
  EXIT /B %_eLvl%
)


:Main


  CALL :Initialize_Variables

    rem --- Start job ---------------------------------------------

  call :start_job

  FOR %A IN (
    Step1
    Step2
    Step3
  ) DO (
    IF /I !_eLvl! LEQ 0 (
      ECHO. Running :%%A
      CALL :%%A
    ) ELSE (
      ECHO Error Occured!  Skipping :%%A
    )
  )

  IF !_eLvl! GTR 0 (
    SET "job_status=FAILED"
  )

  rem --- End job -------------------------------------------------
  call :end_job

GOTO :EOF


:Initialize_Variables
  rem --- Initialize --------------------------------------------

  REM SET "NLS_DATE_FORMAT=RRRR-MM-DD-HH24:MI"

  REM --- Set up the Date Variable
  FOR /F "Tokens=1-7 delims=MTWFSmtwfsouehrandit:-\/. " %%A IN ("%DATE% %TIME: =0%") DO (
    FOR /F "Tokens=2-4 Skip=1 Delims=(-)" %%a IN ('ECHO.^| DATE') DO (
      SET "_%%~a=%%~A"
      SET "_%%~b=%%~B"
      SET "_%%~c=%%~C"
      SET "TIMESTAMP=!_YY!!_mm!!_dd!_%%~D%%~E%%~F"
    )
  )

  REM Setup Logs:
  SET "LOG_FILE=%LOG_DIR%\%process_id%_%TIMESTAMP%.log"
  SET "TMP_FILE=%TMP_DIR%\%process_id%_%TIMESTAMP%.tmp"

  rem Install error handler.
  rem basename=$(basename $0)

  REM Setup the Process Info and default variable States
  SET "process_id=%1"
  SET "job_id="
  SET "process_type="
  SET "preprocess_type="
  SET "postprocess_type="
  SET "job_status=CREATED"
  SET "job_status_message="
  SET "log_level=INFO"
  SET "pre="

GOTO :EOF



:show_usage
  @echo Usage: Usage is run_process.bat ProcessName
GOTO :EOF

:start_job
  rem --- Function definitions ----------------------------------
  rem -----------------------------------------------------------
  rem Function Name: start_job
  rem Description  :
  rem   Retrieve process properties and start a new job for
  rem   the specified process.
  rem Input        : process_id - Process to start.
  rem Output       : job_id - New job id set.
  rem -----------------------------------------------------------

  %_Write-Info%"--- Starting -----------------------------------"
  %_Write-Info%"Process          : %process_id%"
  %_Write-Info%"Environment      : %ENV_NAME%"
  %_Write-Info%"Batch root       : %ENV_HOME%"
  %_Write-Info%"Log file         : "%LOG_FILE%""
  %_Write-Info%"Tmp file         : "%TMP_FILE%" "

  sqlplus -s /nolog @"%dirname%/sqlFile.sql" '%BATCHUSER%' '%BATCHPWD%' '%ORACLE_SID%' '%process_id%'

  for /f "tokens=2 delims=|" %%a in ('findstr /R /I "^JOB_ID" "%TMP_FILE%" ') do SET "JOB_ID=%%a"
  for /f "tokens=1,*" %%a in ("%JOB_ID%") do SET "JOB_ID=%%a"
  for /f "tokens=2 delims=|" %%a in ('findstr /R /I "^PROCESS_TYPE" "%TMP_FILE%" ') do SET "PROCESS_TYPE=%%a"
  for /f "tokens=1,*" %%a in ("%PROCESS_TYPE%") do SET "PROCESS_TYPE=%%a"
  for /f "tokens=2 delims=|" %%a in ('findstr /R /I "^PREPROCESS_TYPE" "%TMP_FILE%" ') do SET "PREPROCESS_TYPE=%%a"
  for /f "tokens=1,*" %%a in ("%PREPROCESS_TYPE%") do SET "PREPROCESS_TYPE=%%a"
  for /f "tokens=2 delims=|" %%a in ('findstr /R /I "^POSTPROCESS_TYPE" "%TMP_FILE%" ') do SET "POSTPROCESS_TYPE=%%a"
  for /f "tokens=1,*" %%a in ("%POSTPROCESS_TYPE%") do SET "POSTPROCESS_TYPE=%%a"
  for /f "tokens=2 delims=|" %%a in ('findstr /R /I "^LOG_LEVEL" "%TMP_FILE%" ') do SET "LOG_LEVEL=%%a"
  for /f "tokens=1,*" %%a in ("%LOG_LEVEL%") do SET "LOG_LEVEL=%%a"

  SET "job_status=RUNNING"
  del /q "%TMP_FILE% ""

  IF "%job_id%" == ""  (
    SET "job_status=FAILED"
    SET "_eLvl=1"
 )

  %_Write-Info%"Job id           : %job_id%"
  %_Write-Info%"Process type     : %process_type%"
  %_Write-Info%"Pre-process type : %preprocess_type%"
  %_Write-Info%"Post-process type: %postprocess_type%"
  %_Write-Info%"--- Running ------------------------------------"  
 goto :eof

:Step1
  (
    ECHO."SQL CMD" | FIND /I /V "%preprocess_type%" (
    ) && (
      %_Write-Info%"No Prerocess_type."
    )
  ) || (
    CALL SET "pre=!%preprocess_type%_DIR!\%process_id%_pre"
    CALL "%FWK_DIR%\run_sql_process.bat" "!pre!.%preprocess_type%"
  )

  SET "_eLvl=%ERRORLEVEL%"
GOTO :EOF

:Step2
  rem --- Execute main process ----------------------------------
  SET "_Valid_Procs=SQL CMD SRE PERL SQLLDR"
  SET "_SQL.Ext=SQL"
  SET "_CMD.Ext=CMD"
  SET "_Perl.Ext=pl"
  SET "_SRE.Ext=xml"

  rem Check is valid Process Type

  ECHO."%_Valid_Procs%" | FIND /I /V "%process_type%" >NUL && (
    %_Write-Info%"Unsupported process type %process_type%."
    SET "job_status=FAILED"
    SET "_eLvl=1"
    GOTO :EOF
  )
  IF /I "%process_type%" EQU "SQLLDR" (
      %_Write-Info%"SQLLDR."
      SET "ldr=%CTL_DIR%\%process_id%"
      SET "log=%LOG_DIR%\%process_id%_%TIMESTAMP%"
      SET "bad=%BAD_DIR%\%process_id%_%TIMESTAMP%"
      SET "data=%IN_DIR%\%process_id%"
      CALL SET "FWK_CMD=%FWK_DIR%\run_SQLLDR_process.bat" !ldr!.ctl !log!.log !bad!.bad !data!.dat %BATCHUSER% %BATCHPWD% %ORACLE_SID%"
  ) ELSE (
    FOR %%A IN (
      %_Valid_Procs%"
    ) DO (
      %_Write-Info%"%%A."
      CALL SET "FWK_CMD="%FWK_DIR%\run_%%A_process.bat" "Main=!%%A_DIR!\%process_id%.!_%%A.ext!""
    )
  )

  %_Write-Info% Running: %FWK_CMD%
  call "%FWK_CMD%"

  SET "_eLvl=%ERRORLEVEL%"
GOTO :EOF

:Step3

  (
    ECHO."SQL CMD" | FIND /I /V "%postprocess_type%" (
    ) && (
      %_Write-Info%"No Prerocess_type."
    )
  ) || (
    CALL SET "pre=!%preprocess_type%_DIR!\%process_id%_post"
    CALL "%FWK_DIR%\run_%preprocess_type%_process.bat" "!pre!.%preprocess_type%"
  )

  SET "_eLvl=%ERRORLEVEL%"
GOTO :EOF




:end_job
  rem -----------------------------------------------------------
  rem Function Name: end_job
  rem Description  :
  rem   End the current job.
  rem Input        : job_id
  rem Output       : N/A
  rem -----------------------------------------------------------
  %_Write-Info%"--- Ending -------------------------------------"


 sqlplus -s /nolog @%dirname%/sqlFileEnd.sql '%BATCHUSER%' '%BATCHPWD%' '%ORACLE_SID%' '%job_id%' '%job_status%'

  for /f "tokens=2 delims=|" %%a in ('findstr /R /I "^JOB_STATUS|" "%TMP_FILE%" ') do SET "JOB_STATUS=%%a"
  for /f "tokens=1,*" %%a in ("%JOB_STATUS%") do SET "JOB_STATUS=%%a"
  for /f "tokens=2 delims=|" %%a in ('findstr /R /I "^JOB_STATUS_MESSAGE" "%TMP_FILE%" ') do SET "JOB_STATUS_MESSAGE=%%a"
  for /f "tokens=1,*" %%a in ("%JOB_STATUS_MESSAGE%") do SET "JOB_STATUS_MESSAGE=%%a"
  for /f "tokens=2 delims=|" %%a in ('findstr /R /I "^JOB_VOLUME" "%TMP_FILE%" ') do SET "JOB_VOLUME=%%a"
  for /f "tokens=1,*" %%a in ("%JOB_VOLUME%") do SET "JOB_VOLUME=%%a"
  for /f "tokens=2 delims=|" %%a in ('findstr /R /I "^JOB_ERROR_COUNT" "%TMP_FILE%" ') do SET "JOB_ERROR_COUNT=%%a"
  for /f "tokens=1,*" %%a in ("%JOB_ERROR_COUNT%") do SET "JOB_ERROR_COUNT=%%a"
  for /f "tokens=2 delims=|" %%a in ('findstr /R /I "^JOB_WARNING_COUNT" "%TMP_FILE%" ') do SET "JOB_WARNING_COUNT=%%a"
  for /f "tokens=1,*" %%a in ("%JOB_WARNING_COUNT%") do SET "JOB_WARNING_COUNT=%%a"

   del /q "%TMP_FILE%"
  %_Write-Info%"Job status       : %job_status%"
  %_Write-Info%"Job status msg   : %job_status_message%"
  rem %_Write-Info%"Volume           : %job_volume%"
  %_Write-Info%"Error count      : %job_error_count%"
  %_Write-Info%"Warning count    : %job_warning_count%"    

  CALL :Cleanup

goto :eof






:cleanup 
   rem -----------------------------------------------------------
   rem Function Name: clear
   rem Description  :
   rem   Handle clean up.
   rem Input        : N/A
   rem Output       : N/A
   rem -----------------------------------------------------------
  if not '%job_status%' == 'COMPLETED' (
    %_Write-Info%"--------- Ended with failure -------------------------"
  ) else (
    %_Write-Info%"----------------------- End --------------------------"
  )
goto :eof



:log_info
  rem -----------------------------------------------------------
  rem Function Name: log_info
  rem Description  :
  rem   Write information to log file and stdout.
  rem Input        : 1 - Message to log.
  rem Output       : N/A
  rem -----------------------------------------------------------
  SET "stamp=%TIMESTAMP%"
  rem echo [INFO.][%stamp%] %1
  rem echo.
  rem echo "%LOG_FILE%"
  echo.[INFO.][%stamp%] %*>> "%LOG_FILE%"
  echo.>> "%LOG_FILE%"
goto :eof
```